# Hello World Library using autotools

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

Creating bin program is really easy using autotools I need to just define two files.

**`Makefile.am'**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

**`configure.in'**

```
AC_INIT(hello.c)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(hello,1.0)
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_INSTALL
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

can any body give a smallest example for creating static **library** using autotools ?

Comment: The syntax you use for `configure.in` is seriously outdated!  Please read the "Hello World" example from the Automake manual for the current syntax. http://sourceware.org/automake/automake.html#Hello-World

Comment: @adi I just started learning it. and found that as example

Comment: Yes, it's a problem when you begin: a lot of tutorials you find on the Internet has been written around 1999-2000 when Automake 1.4 and Autoconf 2.13 were everywhere.   But these tools have been huge improvement over the year, and the syntax changed a lot.  As a rule of thumb, if your document uses `configure.in` instead of `configure.ac`, it is likely to be outdated.  I have a tutorial with up-to-date syntax at http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html if you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Makefile.am**:

```
lib_LIBRARIES = libhello.a
libhello_a_SOURCES = hello.c
```

**configure.ac**:

```
AC_INIT([libhello], [1.0], [bug@libhello.org])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The documentation for building libraries with Automake is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#A-Library).

Comment: @adi I got one more  question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589676/autotools-include-path