# Autotools include path

Tags: autotools

I have a directory structure like

```
Makefile.am
Configure.ac
         src/
             hello.c
             Makefile.am

         include/
             hello.h
```

How to specify the include path in Makefile.am of src so that it includes header files from include/ dir as well as c file depends on header file. 
So if I modify any .h file it force to recompile .cc file.

Defining AM_CPPFLAGS' is giving warning

```
configure.ac:5: warning: macro `AM_CPPFLAGS' not found in library
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In **src/Makefile.am**, write:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

There is no need to mark the dependency between **hello.c** and **hello.h**, [it will be recorded automatically the first time you build your project](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Dependency-Tracking.html#Dependency-Tracking).